# 38CrNiMoAlA: Does it even exist?

Tags: materials, metallurgy, metals, alloys

I have some plungers made of 38CrNiMoAlA. Their required hardness to be achieved via quenching/tempering is 51 HRC. I've scoured our technical order for heat treatment of steel alloys but the material is not there. I even checked the internet, it doesn't seem to exist at all. The closest I could get was 38CrMoAlA. Please help if you know this material or something close to it.

Comment: What is the use of the plunger?

Comment: No element has the symbol "A".

Answer (score 1):

The closest to this grade is AMS 6470 steel, but it does not contain nickel.

Furthermore 51 HRC is easily possible via surface diffusion process like Nitriding to improve wear resistance.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a Russian standard ( GOST ). If so ,it is a low alloy steel with 0.38% C and can be nitrided ( indicated by Al).  Similar to SAE 4340 with additional Al which can be hardened up to HRC 60. What is the component ; could it be a nickel base high alloy ?